# Animation with different speed simultaneously

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation

I want to perform animation of three labels with three different speeds.
label1`with a duration of`1.0 second.
label2`with a duration of`2.5 seconds.
label3`with a duration of`5.0 seconds.

I tried "setAnimationDuration" method, but it was not working.
Could anyone tell, where I am doing wrong?

Edit:
complete Scenario:
I have a scrollview. When I am swiping from right to left, background image is changing as each page of scrollview has different background image. With scrolling, labels also start animating and it seems that they are starting from next page and on complete scrolling, they stop to their specific position.
I am performing animation on the basis of currentoffset.

Code:

```
- (void) scrollviewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(currentOffset > 1024)
        {
          [UIView beginAnimation: nil context:nil];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
          label1.frame = CGRectMake(2048-currentoffset+ 100, Y, Width, Height);
          [UIView commitAnimation];
        }
    if(currentOffset > 1024)
        {
          [UIView beginAnimation: nil context:nil];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration: 2.5];
          label2.frame = CGRectMake(2048-currentoffset+ 100, Y+20, Width, Height);
          [UIView commitAnimation];
        }
    if(currentOffset > 1024)
        {
          [UIView beginAnimation: nil context:nil];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration: 5.0];
          label3.frame = CGRectMake(2048-currentoffset+ 100, Y+20, Width, Height);
          [UIView commitAnimation];
        }
      }
```

The problem is setAnimationDuration is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the code you posted in a method which will be called every second, like so:

```
NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:nil interval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourmethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. I try & will revert back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{
                      label3.frame = CGRectMake(2048-currentoffset+ 100, Y+20, Width, Height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed) {

                 }
];
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working.
I want to start all label at same time, it should animate with different speed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)scrollviewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(currentOffset > 1024) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            label1.frame = CGRectMake(2048-currentoffset+ 100, Y, Width, Height);
        }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 animations:^{
            label2.frame = CGRectMake(2048-currentoffset+ 100, Y+20, Width, Height);
        }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
            label3.frame = CGRectMake(2048-currentoffset+ 100, Y+20, Width, Height);
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need one if statement. You have three.

Comment: @max_ yeah, that's true, I was just copying the op's code. Updated.

Comment: I tried, but it's not working.
The main problem is, frame is changing on the basis of "currentoffset" and not due to animation.
If I delete the animation code, then also it is working same and all labels are changing their frame with same speed.